# Custom header/metadata file

Tags: c#, arrays, file, header, byte

I need to write some code that write X number of bytes:

```
byte[] byteArray = MyFunc.getData();
File.WriteAllBytes(fileName, byteArray);
```

this perfectly work. Next I need to write a custom object at the end or at the start of the file, I do the following:

```
byte[] myObjectArray;
BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
      {
        bf.Serialize(ms, myObject);
        myObjectArray = ms.ToArray();
      }
```

Now my question is: having this new array of byte, how can I write and read it from a file? The first byte array that I write has variable number of bytes, and also the second one can have different dimension.
Can you please help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are asking about but if you question is only about writing new byte array to the end of file, simply open stream to file and use `stream.write(byte[], int, int)` method. If you need to find that array in future i suggest to make some kind of marker that tell you "here is your object that you searching for", for example:

[ xxxxx byte[] xxxxx ] [ #### MARKER #### ] [ xx byte[] xx]

As you can see, every byte after marker is that array you searching for.

Comment: Yes I can, sorry for delay. You can use for example bytes of specific string, but I think about it and this is not goot idea at all, better make two files and pack it to some existing format, ex. zip.

Answer (score 0):

Use `MemoryStream.WriteTo`, which takes a `Stream`. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.writeto(v=vs.110).aspx).

Depending on what you want to do (overwrite the file, append to it, etc.), you might want something like this:

```
ms.WriteTo(File.Create("./path/to/file");
```